# What is the formula Mathematica uses for ZetaZero?

Tags: special-functions, implementation-details

What is the formula/algorithm *Mathematica* uses for the `ZetaZero` command?

Comment: Try contacting wolfram support and ask them.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to look for [Gram points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramPoint.html), which can be approximated by

$g_n \approx 2\pi\exp\left(1 + W\left(\frac{8n+1}{8e}\right)\right),$

where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) and then numerical root finding can zero into $g_n$.

Gram points can help find zeta zeros, which is touched on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86918/93700).

**Edit:** I found this by traversing through DownValues, so it may be way more complicated than this.

Comment: It seems really close, but I need something far more precise. I've been working on the Riemann Hypothesis (yes, I'm well aware that I'll probably never solve it.) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well I will say that `ZetaZero` explicitly assumes RH by looking for Gram points, i.e. it only looks on the critical line.

Comment: Also for what it's worth you can read about using Gram points to find zeros starting on page 119 here: http://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: To add to this: after using the Gram points to bracket a root, the Riemann-Siegel Z function $Z(t)$ is then used for the actual root finding, since it has been designed to be zero whenever $\zeta\left(\frac12+it\right)$ is zero.